# Netbeans groovy code completion not working

Tags: java, netbeans, groovy, gradle

I have created a new Gradle project in Netbeans where I want to use java and groovy classes together. To make it work I have configured my build.gradle with the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDir 'src/main/java'
```

The build process works like a charm: groovy and java classes interoperate transparently. The only annoying thing is the Netbeans code completion. Code completion of java classes does not work from groovy. Let's say I have the following classes:

*my.package1.JavaClass.java

my.package2.GroovyClass.groovy*

From GroovyClass, if I type 'JavaC' and hit CTRL+space the IDE does not present me any help to import and use JavaClass. I have to manually create the import statement. Moreover when I type '.' after the JavaClass instance Netbeans does not show the methods I could call. This happens also for classes included as dependencies.

Comment: I've never tried putting groovy classes in main/java and then hacking the source sets. Does it work if you do it the "normal" way and move it all into main/groovy and get rid of your gradle hack?

Comment: Just tried: I commented the gradle hack and moved all the groovy sources to src/main/groovy. No luck: it does not build now. Java classes cannot find the groovy ones. Any idea?

Comment: I have fixed the build problem using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369033/how-to-use-gradle-java-and-groovy-together but netbeans code completion problems still persist :-(

Comment: The really bad thing is that code completion does not work at all even between groovy classes. I suspect is something related to the Gradle plugin because the JavaGroovyDemo provided in Netbeans works well.