# Errors while configuring groovy in libgdx game

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, libgdx

I began to learn `ligdx` a few time ago. I tried to configure `groovy` to work in the core project of the game, but every time I run the application i get these exceptions:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task :core:compileJava.
>
> Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'core'
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Error:(16, 23) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class testClass
>
> Error:(16, 23) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class testClass

my code is :

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    testClass test = new testClass();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();


}
}
```

and

```
class testClass {

def scddsds(){
    println('scddsds')
}
}
```

The Global gradle file is :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "groovy-test"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
        roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.6:grooid'
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

The gradle build of the core project is :

```
   apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

I am using Android Studio.

Comment: share your `build.gradle`

Comment: I posted it . please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get it working. 
Firstly global `build.gradle` must be configured:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "groovy"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.7'

    }
}
```

I added groovy to the core project only and it seems to work fine.

Then to the gradle build of the core project I added:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDirs = [] } 
        groovy { srcDir "src" }
    }
}
eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
dependencies {
}
```

More info about that "magic" with source sets could be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22394850/5151575) answer.

BTW I created separate folder for groovy classes, so the project structure is like:

```
src   
 --main
    --java
    --groovy
```

Comment: when i added some code to my project and compiled it i got this exception : Error:Android Gradle Build Target: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -92

Comment: is this somehow connected with the current question? 'Cos maybe it's worth asking another one)